# Angular async await not working with Http.get

Tags: angular, async-await, httprequest

I am have a piece of code that makes a http request to get the clients geoLocation and then send it to my API using http.get as a parameter, I have done both correctly but I am stuck with making async functions, I want to get the geoLocation and when it finish and I get it I want to make the request to my API, I have tried many tutorials and similar questions on stack overflow but I'm not able to get it right can someone advice what's wrong with my code?

Here is the code:

```
@Injectable()

export class ProductsService {

  public currency: string = '';
  public catalogMode: boolean = false;

  public compareProducts: BehaviorSubject<Product[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  public observer: Subscriber<{}>;
  public static productList$: Observable<Product[]> = new Observable;
  public static test: boolean = false;

  public ipAddress: string;
  public country: string;

  // Initialize 
  constructor(private http: Http, private toastrService: ToastrService) {
    this.getIp();
    this.compareProducts.subscribe(products => products = products);
  }

  // Observable Product Array
  private products(): Observable<Product[]> {

    ProductsService.productList$.subscribe(p => {
      if (p.length != 0) {
        ProductsService.test = true;
      }
    });

    if (!ProductsService.test) {
      this.currency = this.getCurrency(this.country); //prints counrty = undefined currency = USD
      console.log('currency 1 = ' + this.currency); // prints defualt currency USD?
      ProductsService.productList$ = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/products/getAllProducts?currency='+this.currency).map((res: any) => {
        ProductsService.test = true;
        this.currency = this.getCurrency(this.country);  // calling the function here works as I want
        console.log('currency 2 = ' + this.currency); // prints the expected values
        return res.json();
      });

    }
    return ProductsService.productList$;
  }

  // Get Products
  public getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.products();
  }

  async getIp() {
    await this.http.get(('http://ip-api.com/json/' + '?fields=countryCode')).toPromise().then(r => {
      this.country = r.json().countryCode;
    });
  }

  private getCurrency(country: string): string {
    if (country === 'JO') {
      this.currency = 'JOD';
    } else if (country === 'AE') {
      this.currency = 'AED';
    } else if (country === 'SA') {
      this.currency = 'SAR';
    } else if (country === 'GB') {
      this.currency = 'GBP';
    } else if (country === 'DE') {
      this.currency = 'EUR';
    } else if (country === 'KW') {
      this.currency = 'KWD';
    } else if (country === 'EG') {
      this.currency = 'EGP';
    } else {
      this.currency = 'USD';
    }
    console.log("counrty = " + country + " currency = " + this.currency); //prints counrty = GB currency = GBP
    return this.currency;
  }

}
```

When running the code the console will output:

```
counrty = undefined currency = USD
currency 1 = USD
counrty = GB currency = GBP
currency 2 = GBP
counrty = GB currency = GBP
currency 2 = GBP
```

Comment: Where did you call `getProducts()` function?

Comment: @pindev it gets called from other components

Comment: Is it called before `getIp` is finished?

Comment: I am not sure can you help me out to trace the code? its getting called in ngOnInit() in other components, but note that I have called getIp() in the constructor, and tried to put it at the first line of the products() method but same issue

Comment: You can add `console.log` at the beginning of `getProducts` and `getIp` to make sure which one is first called.

Comment: after adding console.log() in both methods, the one in the getIp got printed first then products()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194667/discussion-between-khaled-and-pindev).

Answer (score 0):

You can call `await this.getIp()` in the `getProducts()` to wait it to be completed.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsServiceService {

  private products: Product[];

  // Initialize
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  // Get Products
  public getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    if (this.products) {
      return of(this.products);
    } else {
      return this.getIp().pipe(
        switchMap(country => {
          const currency = this.getCurrency(country);
          console.log('currency 1 = ' + currency);
          return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/products/getAllProducts?currency=' + currency).pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
              console.log('currency 2 = ' + currency); // prints the expected values
              return res.json();
            })
          );
        })
      );
    }
  }

  getIp() {
    return this.http.get<any>(('http://ip-api.com/json/' + '?fields=countryCode')).pipe(
      map(r => r.json().countryCode)
    );
  }

  private getCurrency(country: string): string {
    let currency;

    if (country === 'JO') {
      currency = 'JOD';
    } else if (country === 'AE') {
      currency = 'AED';
    } else if (country === 'SA') {
      currency = 'SAR';
    } else if (country === 'GB') {
      currency = 'GBP';
    } else if (country === 'DE') {
      currency = 'EUR';
    } else if (country === 'KW') {
      currency = 'KWD';
    } else if (country === 'EG') {
      currency = 'EGP';
    } else {
      currency = 'USD';
    }
    console.log('counrty = ' + country + ' currency = ' + currency);
    return currency;
  }

}
```

Comment: this helped me in getting the ip and the currency before the products, but I got the api called multiple times again!!

Comment: Oh, I missed one thing. Add `this.products = res.json();` before `return res.json();`

Comment: i did that but it didn’t work, it works after the 3rd call

Answer (score 0):

Async/Await doesn't really work like that.
You have to assign the promise to a variable, something like this:

```js
async getIp() {
  const resposne = await this.http.get('http://ip-api.com/json/' + '?fields=countryCode').toPromise();
 ..... do stuff with your response ....
  }
```